# How can i create a new column with different sets of value depending on index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to create a new columns for a DataFrame which will contain value depending on the set of index

Heres the DataFrame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'], 
                          } )
```

Heres what i want to get:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'], 
                      'new_value': ['1', '1', '2', '2']
                      } )
```

i want to create a new column based on the set of index.

Comment: what is the logic here? `df['new_value'] = (np.arange(len(df)) // 2 + 1`?

Comment: @ansev well i have football dataset i want to add round column; for every 10 match i want to assign one value.

Comment: the value you should assign follows the sequence 1,2,3?. I mean do you need `df['new_value'] = (np.arange(len(df)) // 10 + 1` ? Or do you need to select what number to assign to each interval?

Comment: I  posted the answer in comments before...

Comment: @ansev Yep, like a count for every 10 value. e.g for first 10 rows i want value 1 and from 10-20 rows i want value 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have football dataset i want to add round column; for every 10 match i want to assign one value.

Use integer division if default `RangeIndex` by `10` and add `1`:

```
data['new_value'] = data.index // 10  + 1
```

Or if need general solution create helper array:

```
data['new_value'] = np.arange(len(data)) // 10 + 1
```

Comment: @ansev - Sure, in comment.

Comment: @ansev sorry i was bit occupied didn't see your comment. Thanks anyway